# document.getElementByID not working when used as Custom Javascript variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a GTM snippet to filter out pageviews when I'm logged to my blog. In Wordpress, which I use actually, this is true if you can find a DIV element with ID #wpadminbar in your page.

I have built a GTM Variable called `WP Admin Bar Content` which I set this way:

[image]

and a Custom Javascript variable called `Is WP Admin Bar Visible` I defined as:

```
function() {
  var adminbar = {{WP Admin Bar Content}};
if (adminbar == '' || adminbar == null || adminbar == 'null' ) { 
return false; 
} else { 
return true; 
}
}
```

This works. But since I don't need the variable WP Admin Bar, but only the boolean flag, when I did some spring cleaning in my CTM container I tried this, instead:

```
function() {
  var adminbar = document.getElementById("wpadminbar").value;
if (adminbar == '' || adminbar == null || adminbar == 'null' ) { 
return false; 
} else { 
return true; 
}
}
```

This doesn't work any more. `adminbar` is always undefined and the variable at whole is always false.

For some reason when the Var is being set, in my opinion the DOM is probably not ready. But I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: document.getDocumentById?

Comment: whops :) but the typo was in SO only so, still not working...

Comment: Try .innerHTML or .textContent. .value is for form values, I believe

Comment: tnx, it works. But I'm still facing an Issue. If the #wpadminbar is present, the variable is set to 'true' as expected. If not, the var is undefined (I expected it to false, actually)

Comment: Add a check to see if adminbar is undefined, eg. if (adminbar == undefined ....).

Comment: I also think you should also remove the check for the word null (in quotes) as this doesn't truly indicate that adminbar is not defined (since it is equal to the string "null").

Comment: Or potentially do the reverse and check for True?

Comment: Tried all your suggested fixes, no ways. I added the string 'null' only because sometimes GTM set null variables to this value (weird). I think it's a GTM-related behaviour, at the end of the day...